# Rails - Handle asset not precompiled error caused by user's browser cache

Tags: ruby-on-rails, caching, sprockets, precompile

I'm currently developing an app and i'm testing it on Heroku along with other QA testers.

During development i sometimes delete assets that where precompiled, which makes the QA testers receive `AssetNotPrecompiled` error for assets that no longer exists. The error dissapears when clearing the cache.

My question is: How can I handle these cases when the site is live in production? I can't ask my users to clear their cache whenever I delete an asset. I'm sure this is a newb question, but nontheless..

Thanks!

Uri

Comment: have you tried https://github.com/heroku/rails_12factor ?

Comment: I have it in my gemfile. But nothing more then that. How should I use it in this case?